# Setting DIV Content With JS Not Working, So Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I'm trying to replace a div's content with a sourceURL and it works in just a flat html setup, but when I try to incorporate it into a php page it doesn't want to work and I can't figure out why.

..and yes I'm loading jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
$(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://forexfbi.com/"+sourceURL+"");
}
</script>
```

and

```
echo "<tr class=\"expand-child\"><td colspan=\"11\" height=\"100px\">$name1<br>"; ?> <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'Earnings-Disclaimer.html');">Link 1</a> <?php echo"<div id=\"content\"></div></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with checking browser console to see the error. It may be a possible jquery confict in your php file.

Please state the error you found on console. press f12 and click on console.

Comment: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
 
jquery-1.3.2.min.js, line 127 character 344

Comment: perfect. now see this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/permission-denied-error-in-jquery-1-3-2-min-js